# How do I stop this json from escaping html?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, json

I have an ajax control that returns user comments. Its served by a c# ajax handler page and the c# matches a timespan that a user can leave in the comments:

```
commmentToDisplay = Regex.Replace(c.CommentText, timeSpanRegex, "<a href=\'\' onclick=\'alert(\'Flash Required\');\'>" + actualTimeSpan + "</a>");
```

This produces the following json:

```
 ({
     "numOfPages":"1",
     "pageIndex":"1",
     "comments": [
         {
             "user":"hmladmin",
             "created":"29/03/2011 16:41:20",
             "id":"1",
             "comment":"<a href='' onclick='alert('Flash Required');'>00:00:21</a>",
             "editable":"true",
             "reportable":"true"
         }
]
})
```

Confusingly when I look at the html in firebug it comes out as:

```
<a );="" required="" flash="" onclick="alert(" href="">00:00:21</a>
```

Ive tried:

```
commmentToDisplay = Regex.Replace(c.CommentText, timeSpanRegex, "<a href=\'\' onclick=\'alert(\"Flash Required\");\'>" + actualTimeSpan + "</a>");
```

and

```
commmentToDisplay = Regex.Replace(c.CommentText, timeSpanRegex, "<a href=\'\' onclick=\"alert(\"Flash Required\");\">" + actualTimeSpan + "</a>");
```

And multiple permutations of I just cannot work out how to get the json and c# to return an anchor tag with an alert message in the onclick event.

Can someone help me to work out how I escape this properly so this problem doesnt happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you create the string of HTML and has nothing to do with JSON:

```
"<a href=\'\' onclick=\'alert(\'Flash Required\');\'>" + actualTimeSpan + "</a>"
```

should probably be:

```
'<a href="something-sensible.html" onclick="alert(&quot;Flash Required&quot;); return false;">' + actualTimeSpan + '</a>'
```

Comment: I suspect this won't work.  The HTML parser will expand the &quot; first so the JSON parser will be confused by nested double quotes: onclick="alert("Flash Required"); return false;"

Comment: No, it won't. The JSON parser will decode to a JavaScript object. That object will contain a string of HTML. That HTML contains an attribute value. That attribute value contains some JS. The JS has to be HTML encoded to appear in an attribute value. The HTML has to be JSON encoded to appear as a JSON String. The only problem I foresee is that inserting JS via `innerHTML` is generally unreliable.

Comment: You're right.  It depends on how the JSON is delivered.  If it was delivered embedded in a script tag then it would behave as I described, but he's already said he's using ajax.

Comment: `<script>` elements are defined as containing CDATA in the HTML spec (in XHTML authors are expected to use explicit CDATA markers, and this fragment would invalidate the document if said markers were not present). In CDATA sections, entities are **not** expanded.

Comment: You're right again!  I've been working on a pure XHTML project where character entities are expanded in script elements.  I'd never noticed that HTML works differently.

Comment: funny because I just tried it and I can confirm that 'IT WORKS'!!! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You've got nested single quotes in `'alert('Flash Required');'` which won't work.  You need to change one set to double-quotes then escape them (`\"`) for JSON. e.g. `'alert(\"Flash Required\");'`